# SearchBar text only working viewDidLoad

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiwebview, uisearchbar

I have `UIWebView` for displays content. I need to search some text inside webview. I used UISearchBar. But the code is not searching and highlighting.

below code is not working:

.h file:

```
@interface detailsArtViewController : UIViewController<UISearchBarDelegate>
{

    UISearchBar *searchbar;

}
```

.m file:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
   searchbar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];


searchbar.delegate=self;

[wbCont addSubview:searchbar];
}

- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar 
{
     NSLog(@"search is %@",searchBar.text);

[self highlightAllOccurencesOfString:searchBar.text];
}
```

Comment: code. I didn't use XIB. Is respondsToselector correct?

Comment: I referred here http://zframework.ph/how-to-search-a-string-inside-uiwebview/

Comment: After click search key from keyboard nothing happen

Comment: can you check my edited code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you set delegate for `UISearchBar`

In your reference  link itself they set delegate for `UISearchBar`

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UISearchBarDelegate>
{
 UISearchBar *mysearchbar;
}
```

They are setting the delegate in XIB . If you are not using XIB . the set

delegate like  `mysearchbar.delegate =self;`

then only  delegate methods of `UISearchBar`  like ,

```
- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
```

will be called

Please change .m file code as follows

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];
    searchbar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
    searchbar.delegate=self;
    [wbCont addSubview:searchbar];
}

- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar 
{
      //  NSString *search=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Code"];
      NSString *search=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",searchBar.text];
      NSLog(@"search is %@",search);
      [self highlightAllOccurencesOfString:search];
}
```

Comment: No. It's not highlighting the text. But nslog is coming search is Act

Comment: If i press search button in uisearch bar it open keyboard. In keyboard  if i click search then nslog coming

Answer (score 1):

The correct method would be

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
```

not

```
- (void)ViewDidLoad
```

And you should include this in your `-viewDidLoad` method:

```
[super viewDidLoad];
```

I'm not exactly sure what you mean by "not working", but in the first method you draw the search bar to the view, where in the second method.... you don't.

Comment: I used [super viewDidLoad]. If i use this code inside viewDidLoad [self highlightAllOccurencesOfString:searchbar.text]; working and highlighting the text. But if i use inside searchBarSearchButtonClicked: method nothing happen. why?

Comment: when i click search button it's not working. It's working only the search text appear on viewDidLoad.

Comment: @user2955041 Looks all okay to me, so the search bar shows, and when you click search nothing happens (-searchBarSearchButtonClicked isn't fired?)

Comment: @user2955041 Nothing going on in IB?

Comment: @user2955041 Strange, with the current code you've provided, I can't really think of more.